# A lambda that takes no parameters

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin I would like to create a lambda that takes no parameters and returns nothing. I know how to do this when it takes a string parameter and returns nothing:

```
private var mOnTextWatcherCallback: ((m: String) -> Unit)? = null
```

But how do I do it for no parameters?

Comment: You don't need `m: `, just `(String) -> Unit`. You can name the parameter when it's useful, here it isn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use empty parentheses:

```
private var mOnTextWatcherCallback: (() -> Unit)? = null
//                                   ^^
```

Comment: Can that be reduced to something even shorter?

Comment: @AndroidDev No.

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: @AndroidDev Maybe if you remove the whitespace, but I'm not sure if that compiles. Plus it might look a little ugly.

Comment: @byxor Definitely still compiles without the whitespace but ugly indeed.